# MVC 4 DropDownList can't add to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

Hi I am new to MVC 4 and have run into an error when trying to use Html.DropDownList.

Here is my current code.

Model for Jobs:

```
  namespace Payroll.CORE
  {
  public class Job
  {
     public int JobID { get; set; }
     public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Model for Employee:

```
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int CellNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public int BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string PayInterval { get; set; }
    public double NormalRate { get; set; }
    public double OvertimeRate { get; set; }
    public double SetHours { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfEmployment { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastPaymentRecieved { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public int JobID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Absent> Absents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bonus> Bonuses { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HoursWorked> HoursWorkeds { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Payrolls> Payrolls { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Deduction> Deductions { get; set; }
```

View:

```
     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ListSL")

    </div>
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        List<SelectListItem> jobs = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<Job> list = bll.GetJobCatergories();

        foreach (var a in list)
        {
            jobs.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = a.JobTitle, Value = a.JobID.ToString()       });
        }

        ViewBag.ListSL = jobs;
        return View();
    }
```

I now have no way of getting the value of JobID into my model. I have tried using @Html.DropDownListFor but cant get it to populate with the SelectListItem.

I really have no problem getting it to work with hiddenfields or anything so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Edit:
Sorry should have been a bit more clear.  I am creating an employee and the employee gets assigned a job.So I am trying to add the selected Items list value  to the Value int JobID in Employee.

Also the values are showing in the dropdownlist, I need to add the selected value to the employee model when submitting.

Comment: You've posted the Controller there, rather than the Model. Let's have a look at the Model, and we'll have a better idea of what's needed.

Comment: @barrick Yeah sorry that was what I wanted to add plan but seems like my concentration wasn't all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now the model's there, try:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(mdl => mdl.Job.JobID,
                      new SelectList(ViewBag.ListSL,
                          "Value",
                          "Text",
                          Model.JobID),
                      "-- Please Select --")
```

I'd also add that, personally, I don't like the use of ViewBag, as you lose the static typing and hence need that cast back to the SelectList in this case. Whenever I need a drop down list, I have a static property on the model that returns all the items that will populate the drop down list, so I end up with, for example:

```
new SelectList(Model.AllJobs,....)
```

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I am a bit tired and got all confused when adding the question. As for as I understand your answer you are adding the value to the job model? I need to add it too the employee JobID. My strongly typed model is employee.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to change your model for the above answer to work, although I don't think you need a separate JobID field if you have the foreign key to the Job entity - presumably, in this model, `Model.JobID` will always be the same as `Model.Job.JobID`? Try the first solution - the bit about ViewBag won't affect it and is just a personal preference; it doesn't affect functionality.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it gives me a null reference. Let me just make sure we are on the same level. These classes are generated by Entity Framework. I am creating an employee and have created an auto generated View for create employee. When I create an employee I have a dropdownlist where you select the employee job and that is generated from the database as a List<Job>. The Job in the class is the link it created with entity framework because it has a many to one relationship from Employee to Job.

Comment: Okay, I see. In that case, if this is the Create view, and there's no job selected in the model when it is rendered, then remove the `Model.JobID` bit (keep the close bracket and the comma).

Comment: @RudolphOpperman Ha ha!! Glad to be of help. I might remember that - I do want to see a SA v England in a Test at Newlands!

Comment: @RudolphOpperman Just a quick explanation - that line we removed was to set the selected value based on what was in the model. In the Create View, there's nothing set yet, so you got the Null Reference Exception. If you make an Edit View for this, keep that line in, as it will set the drop down to whatever value the Employee Job already has.

Comment: Creating a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one using `new SelectList(ViewBag.ListSL, ....)` is pointless, as is adding the last parameter (`Model.JobID`) since that is ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method.

Answer (score 1):

As i cant see your model...

`@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.JobIdSelected, 
    new SelectList(Model.JobId, "Value", Model.JobId)
)`

In your model create a property, JobIdSelected and it will bind.

Note you will loose your Original Select list, so if you have any model errors, you will need to resend the list back to the view.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have updated my question to show my models. I already have an JobID in employee and need to add the selected value from DropdownBox to the model employee when I click submit.

Comment: I think you should return a model from the controller rather than using the ViewBag, you will get more benifits if you refactor the code in the future...

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListSL)
```

This binds the selected value to the property JobID, using ViewBag.ListSL as the options

Comment: The problem is that I do not have a SelectList I have selectListItem and cannot cast (SelectListItem)ViewBag.ListSL. Is there and easy way to conver List<SelectListItem> -> SlectList?

Comment: Then use `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListSL`

Comment: Ok I used that but now on submitting I Get this error. There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'JobID'.

Comment: If `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobID)` works correctly, then `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListSL)` will work, but why does your model have properties `int JobID` and `Job Job` which also includes property `int JobID`? Also have your declared your model in the view, i.e. `@model YourAssembly.Employee`? In addition your controller should return the model, i.e `return View(new Employee())`

Comment: The class was generated by EF it shows that it has a one to many link between EMployee and Job. Yeah I have declared my @model, It was auto generated by Razer as strongly type view with the create template. And with working I meant it populated the List with values. But I could not retrieve the value when I pressed the submit button. Would I be able to get the value with Formcollection from the dropdownList?

Comment: You can check `Request.Form.AllKeys` to make sure the property is posted back, but the `ModelBinder` should bind the properties of Employee correctly if there are no errors. You haven't included your post method, but it should be `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(Employee employee) {..`